# error in set and get methods

Tags: java, class, abstract

i am a 1st year IT Student taking OOP...

i have this abstract parent Class...

```
public abstract class Person{
private String Name;

protected Person(){
    setName("xxxxxxxx");
}

public abstract String getName();
public abstract void setName(String name);
```

}

and this is its child class...

```
public class PetOwner extends Person{
private boolean hasKids;
private boolean hasAllergies;

public PetOwner(){
       setName("xxxx");
       setAllergies(true);
       setKids(true);
}

public PetOwner(String name, boolean a, boolean k){
    setName(name);
    setKids(k);
    setAllergies(a);
}

public String getName(){return Name;}
public void setName(String n){ Name = n;}

public boolean getAllergies(){return hasAllergies;}
public void setAllergies(boolean a){hasAllergies = a;}

public boolean getKids(){return hasKids;}
public boolean setKids(boolean k){hasKids = k;}
```

}

when i compile the child class it has errors that  the "Name" is a private variable of Person.

my question is how can i access the private variables of the parent class in my child class by not changing it to public or protected??

Comment: It should be either Internal or Public, You cant access private members

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't define your name setters and getters as abstract if you dont want to change "String Name" access modifier to public or protected. Do this:

```
public String getName(){return Name;} 
public void setName(String name){Name = name;}
```

2. In your child class; Do this:

```
public String getName(){return super.getName();}
public void setName(String n){ super.setName(n);}
```

**On Another Note:** You're not assigning value to Name in your super class constructor. Write Name = xxxx instead because you are calling a setter that is abstract!

Comment: Is it still not compiling?

Comment: The solution I told you will definitely work, If you tell me more I can solve it.

Comment: when i remove the abstract from the methods on the abstract class it says "missing function body or abstract"

Comment: Hey @KevinBigay, When you remove abstract keyword from parent class, you need to give default implementation. I mentioned this in my point number one.

Answer (score 0):

`private` members are private to the entity they are defined in. `protected` are private to the entity they are defined and to their subclasses. `public` means no protection/accessible everywhere.

Roughly, if you define an attribute in a given entity then almost all the management of it should be defined at the same place. It means that if a `Person` has a `name` then the method `setName` and `getName` should be defined in `Person`. They could be redefined in subclasses but they should at least be defined in `Person`.

Think about it: why would you like (in common cases) every `PetOwner` or `ClergyMan` to define `setName`? They will probably both do exactly the same; so factoring the definition in `Person` is the right way.

Comment: should i make an interface instead of an abstract class??

Comment: No, `person`  is partially defined, so it is not an interface.